# Sharepoint 2010 xsl @PublishingPageImage is showing blank text in List Web Part

Tags: xslt, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm working on implementing a custom news excerpt list view for a site. It has 4 fields,

- Title
- Short Article
- URL to full article
- Image

Currently, I was successfully able to make it look right using 4 basic text fields in the list edit form, however, there is a feature in Sharepoint that allows the user to select a published image from the server using a built in browser. This image is then stored as html in the field "PublishingPageImage". I'm realizing, however, that any fields with html in them are getting returned as blank for some reason, and when I switched my basic URL text field over to the Published Image type, this is occurring. In addition, the link html no longer displays using Sharepoint's Hyperlink field type.

I've tried using a lot of suggested methods on the web, however, they have all been throwing errors on the web part for me.

```
    Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists, contact your Web server administrator.


    Correlation ID:ae8f04be-849f-454f-843a-d2f7487b31d8
```

Any suggestions to my code here would be appreciated, I'm fairly new to the world of xsl. Sharepoint Designer appears to show no problems with the xsl.

```
<!--
This section is the set up and can be used at the top of any external XSLT stylesheet file
-->
<xsl:stylesheet
xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp"
version="1.0"
exclude-result-prefixes="xsl msxsl ddwrt"
xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime"
xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20"
xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls"
xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="no"/>
<!--
End of Set Up
-->
<!--
The initial template which in this case is matching everything with "/"
It then creates a variable called Rows - this is accessed as $Rows
A standard HTML table and header row with the names of our columns is next followed by a loop through each row of the list and calls our second template dvt1-rowview to display the contents
-->
<xsl:template match="/" xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsl:variable name="Rows" select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Transportation/Styles/styles.css" />
<ul class="section-list">
<xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
<xsl:call-template name="dvt_1.rowview" />
</xsl:for-each>
</ul>
</xsl:template>
<!--
End of first template
-->
<!--
Standard HTML rows and cells contain the contents of our list row
xsl:value-of command is used to display our columns
Columns are accessed as @InternalColumnName
-->
<xsl:template name="dvt_1.rowview">
<li>

<xsl:if test="@PublishingPageImage != ''">
        <xsl:value-of select="@PublishingPageImage" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
</xsl:if>

<h3><xsl:value-of select="@Title" /></h3>
<p><xsl:value-of select="@Short_Content"/></p>


<p><xsl:value-of select="@Link" disable-output-escaping="yes"/></p>
</li>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out, the problem wasn't with the xslt, it was just a sharepoint quirk. I'll answer this in case anyone stumbles upon the same issue.

As I mentioned before, I was using the List Web part, and XSLT for List View, or XLV. To add the images to the list view I wanted, first, I added the Page Image (it can be another publishing image field as well) to the list itself. Then I added it to the list view I was displaying on the webpage. Then, in the web part settings for the list, I had to again, point the web part to the updated list view. Sharepoint itself probably generates its own xsl cache at this point which is why I had to point it to the list view again when the list view was modified.

A good little snippet I found that helped solve this problem is:

```
<xsl:for-each select="@*">
    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
    <xsl:text> = </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/><br/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

source: http://benprins.wordpress.com/2012/05/20/show-all-fields-and-values-with-xslt/

When nested inside a row template, it gives you each field name and value for each row. This is good if you want to check and see if your field is showing up, or to find the specific name of a field, or

Answer (score 2):

showing image

take column value of image in img src like in following example

```
<xsl:variable name="url" >
     <xsl:value-of select="@PublishingPageImage" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
  </xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="imglink" select="substring-before($url,',')" > </xsl:variable>
<div class="image"><img src="{$imglink}" width="296px;" height="200px;"></img></div>
```

Comment: Its still not loading any image, I copied that example and src for the image is empty.

Comment: I'm wondering, is there a setting I need to enable to allow publishing images to be attached to the list?